# c# Error Message - Type Or namespace definition or end of file expected

Tags: c#

All, I am writing a c# script where I want to check if a windows pop-up titled "Script Error" is visible and return True or False. To do this I have had to use *static extern* which I believe I am using incorrectly but not sure how to correct.

Please can someone advise how to resolve the error I am seeing:

Error Message - Type Or namespace definition or end of file expected

**Please note the parenthesis which are causing the issue I have labelled Error Parethesis however I am not entirely sure these are causing the overall issue.

Please see full code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace Dynamic.Script_8D737880D773F26
{ **Error Parathesis
   // Script generated by Pega Robotics Studio 8.0.2032.0
   // Please use caution when modifying class name, namespace or attributes
  [OpenSpan.TypeManagement.DynamicTypeAttribute()]
  [OpenSpan.Design.ComponentIdentityAttribute("Script-8D737880D773F26")]
  public sealed class Script
  {
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr zeroOnly, string lpWindowName);
  }
  {
    public bool ScriptErrorVisible()
    {
      if (FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Script Error") != IntPtr.Zero)
      {
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
   }
} **Error Parenthesis
```

Comment: The Script class appears to end right after the extern method, leaving the method at namespace level

Comment: i think this is a good indication of why you need to use indenting correctly.  Its then clear where brackets are missing (or erroneous)

Comment: Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing are you able to recommend what is incorrect - Apologies if this is a basic error very new to c#

Comment: see the two answers below...

Comment: This question really is about bad indenting and not having brackets match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others have said, a good place to start would be to indent properly. To actually explain your issue rather than just post the answer, see the below explanation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace Dynamic.Script_8D737880D773F26
{
    // Script generated by Pega Robotics Studio 8.0.2032.0
    // Please use caution when modifying class name, namespace or attributes
    [OpenSpan.TypeManagement.DynamicTypeAttribute()]
    [OpenSpan.Design.ComponentIdentityAttribute("Script-8D737880D773F26")]
    public sealed class Script
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr zeroOnly, string lpWindowName);
    } // << Your class ends here

    { // << Opened brackets without declaring a class
        public bool ScriptErrorVisible()
        {
            if (FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Script Error") != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } // << This would close the class, but you haven't declared one
} // << This ends the namespace
```

So this is the answer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace Dynamic.Script_8D737880D773F26
{
    // Script generated by Pega Robotics Studio 8.0.2032.0
    // Please use caution when modifying class name, namespace or attributes
    [OpenSpan.TypeManagement.DynamicTypeAttribute()]
    [OpenSpan.Design.ComponentIdentityAttribute("Script-8D737880D773F26")]
    public sealed class Script
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr zeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

        public bool ScriptErrorVisible()
        {
            if (FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Script Error") != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        } // << Closes the ScriptErrorVisible method
    } // << Closes the Script class
} // << Closes the Dynamic.Script_8D737880D773F26 namespace
```

Comment: @astaraxia thanks for the explanation its much appreciated. I have now implemented your code however an error returning - Type or namespace not found for DllIImport, EntryPoint,SetlastError. Any ideas on how I would fix this?

Comment: I believe you need to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices` to your using statements in order to use DllImport.

Comment: @astaraxia thanks so much, and thank you for taking your time to explain the answer! All working perfectly now!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you had a couple of hanging brackets. Try this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace Dynamic.Script_8D737880D773F26
{
    // Script generated by Pega Robotics Studio 8.0.2032.0
    // Please use caution when modifying class name, namespace or attributes
    [OpenSpan.TypeManagement.DynamicTypeAttribute()]
    [OpenSpan.Design.ComponentIdentityAttribute("Script-8D737880D773F26")]
    public sealed class Script
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr zeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

        public bool ScriptErrorVisible()
        {
            if (FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Script Error") != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: @SB999: When code has *right indents* erroneous `{...}` are *evident*

Comment: @Christopher Norris still gets the same error I was receiving :S

Comment: @Sb999. I do not experience the same error message you have:
Type Or namespace definition or end of file expected

Are you still getting this message?